# Gimp, scale a layer and Snap to Guide

Tags: gimp, guides

Is it possible to Enable Snap to Guide for Scaling in Gimp?
Currently moving a layer and Snapping to Guides works fine but Scaling and Snaping doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Scale Transform Tool <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> doesn't seem to work with snapping to guides. Not sure why this is. Perhaps it's a bug*?

However, the Universal Transform Tool <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> can also be used for scaling, and does seem to snap to guides just fine.

After selecting the tool and clicking on the image, click and drag one of the middle square handles on any side, and it should snap to a guide.

Example

[image]

*Note: After a little more research, I believe Universal Transform is a newer feature of GIMP 2.10, so perhaps this explains the difference in behaviour compared to the Scale Tool.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I don't understand why the Scale Transform Tool nas not Snapping option, but the Universal Transform Tool does do the trick.